# Unable to load the AWS console home login page

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have been learning AWS. from couple of days i am not able to load the home AWS login page and get into it. i have checked the firewall and tried shutting it down as well. i have cleared the browser cache, resetting etc. everything else is working fine on the system. please let me know which direction to be followed to get this back again.

At the moment it feels like my home has become a no fly zone for AWS  site signals. cant open the same in phone as well..

Comment: What happens when you try to load the page?

Comment: The behaviour is like the page is timeout ..

Comment: The usual timeout behavior is to show the login page. As that's clearly not the case for you, please elaborate what happens in that situation.